# Me sale un error relacionado con configuraciones de proxy cuando intento instalar Cypress en Ubuntu con el comando: npm install cypress --save-dev

Tags: cypress

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que problema ocurre ya que estoy usando un proxy automatico en la maquina y ademas no existe ningun proxy en la direccion /etc/apt/apt.conf.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya solucioné este problema. La cuestión es que vivo en Cuba y al parecer la distribución de contenido de paquetes npm en su sitio oficial https://registry.npmjs.org/ esta boqueado para Cuba.

Por tanto, si alguien mas tiene problemas con la instalación de paquetes npm y le sale un error parecido a este (npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/cypress failed, reason: read ECONNRESET), tienen dos opciones para tener en cuenta:

1- utilizar otra CDN o mirror el cual permita la distribucion de contenido, en este caso para el uso de paquetes  npm. A mi m sirvió este mirror: https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/npm/

2- Utilizar VPN  :)